# Separating KeyListener and JFrame into 2 different classes

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel, keypress, keylistener

I will show you two different codes to demonstrate what i'm asking for.
The First code work fine it includes the JFrame and KeyListener in one class however what i want is to separate them.

**First Code Below...**

```
public class Fgui extends JFrame implements KeyListener{

private JPanel jp;
private Icon background = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("back2.png"));
private Icon monster = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("mol.png"));
protected JLabel mon;
private JLabel backG;
protected int monX = 300;
private int monY = 225;
protected int monDX = 0;
private int monDY = 0;
protected JLabel ct = new JLabel("Change Text");
protected int code;

public Fgui(){

    super("Crazy Monster Eating Game");
    this.setSize(750,400);
    this.setLayout(null);

    mon = new JLabel(monster);
    backG = new JLabel(background);

    this.addKeyListener(this);

    this.add(mon);
    mon.setSize(150,150);
    mon.setLocation(monX, 225);

    this.add(ct);
    ct.setSize(750,20);
    ct.setLocation(0,0);

    this.add(backG);
    backG.setSize(750,400);
    backG.setLocation(0,0);
}
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    code = e.getKeyCode();
    if(code == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){ 

        monDX = -40; 
        ct.setText("left key pressed");
        monX = monDX+monX;

        }
    else if(code == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){

        monDX = 40;
        ct.setText("right key pressed");
        monX = monDX+monX;

}else if(code == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE){

    try{ct.setText("ESC key pressed");
    this.dispose();}catch(Exception excep){System.out.println("Failed to EXIT!");}

}else{
    ct.setText("Key not registred");
    }
    mon.setLocation(monX, 225);
}
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {} 
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}
}
```

Then i tried to separate them and ended up with the following code,

**Second Code...**

**JFrame Half**

```
public class Fgui extends JFrame {

private JPanel jp;
private Icon background = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("back2.png"));
private Icon monster = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("mol.png"));
protected JLabel mon;
private JLabel backG;
protected int monX = 300;
private int monY = 225;
protected int monDX = 0;
private int monDY = 0;
protected JLabel ct = new JLabel("Change Text");
protected int code;

public Fgui(){

    super("Crazy Monster Eating Game");
    this.setSize(750,400);
    this.setLayout(null);

    mon = new JLabel(monster);
    backG = new JLabel(background);

    KeyL KeyLObj = new KeyL();
    this.addKeyListener(KeyLObj);

    this.add(mon);
    mon.setSize(150,150);
    mon.setLocation(monX, 225);

    this.add(ct);
    ct.setSize(750,20);
    ct.setLocation(0,0);

    this.add(backG);
    backG.setSize(750,400);
    backG.setLocation(0,0);
}

}
```

**KeyListener Half**

```
public class KeyL extends Fgui implements KeyListener{

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    code = e.getKeyCode();
    if(code == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){ 

        monDX = -40; 
        ct.setText("left key pressed");
        monX = monDX+monX;

        }
    else if(code == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){

        monDX = 40;
        ct.setText("right key pressed");
        monX = monDX+monX;

}else if(code == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE){

    try{ct.setText("ESC key pressed");
    this.dispose();}catch(Exception excep){System.out.println("Failed to EXIT!");}

}else{
    ct.setText("Key not registred");
    }
    mon.setLocation(monX, 225);
}
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {} 
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}
}
```

The Second Code here has two separate classes one is JFrame class the other is for KeyListener class but when i compile it, it does not work. I assume it is the problem with me adding the addKeyListener statement in a wrong way.

```
KeyL KeyLObj = new KeyL();
    this.addKeyListener(KeyLObj);
```

I tried adding it through the KeyL class but it didn't work either.

The reason i want to do this is because i don't want the code to be cramped all in one class, but separate it into 2 to make it seem more clean. And if i want to add more key events i can just do it in that one class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're seeing is pretty simple. Because you make `KeyL` a subclass of `Fgui`, every time a new `KeyL` is constructed, all of the `Fgui` initialization code will get run.

So you get to this line:

```
KeyL KeyLObj = new KeyL();
```

That creates a new `KeyL`, so before that line finishes, a new `KeyL` object has to be created. Since a `KeyL` is an `Fgui`, the `Fgui` constructor gets called. And the `FGui` constructor eventually gets to that same line, `KeyL KeyLObj = new KeyL();`, so the process repeats itself. You can never get past that line, because each new `KeyL` needs to make another `KeyL` before it can be fully constructed, so the program just keeps making new objects until it runs out of space.

The answer is that there's no reason for `KeyL` to be a `Fgui`. Make it just implement `KeyListener`, and not extend `Fgui`. Then, make sure it has access to all the variables it needs to accomplish its task.

Most of your variables **should not** be fields in the object; they should just be local variables. Anything that doesn't need to exist outside that function, or keep it's value between calls, should be changed to a local variable. It looks like the only two that matter are `mon`, `ct`, and the `Fgui` which you reference with `this`. So make those arguments into `KeyL`'s constructor (as two `JLabel`s and a `JFrame`), and then call your methods on those.